# pandas new column on condition

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, sum, row

i have a dataframe like this :

```
 Name    one two 
 John     A   20
 John     P   30
 Alex     B   40
 David    C   50
 Harry    A   60
 Harry    P   40
```

I want to add those rows where `A` and `P` are simultaneously occurring for the specific names such as

```
 Name  one  two 
 John  A+P 50 
 Alex  B   40  
 David C   50  
 Harry A+P 100
```

I tried with `sum` function of row wise in `pandas` but didn't got output as in such form needed. Kindly help me out !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) with `join` and `sum`:

```
df = df.groupby('Name', sort=False, as_index=False).agg({'one':'+'.join, 'two':'sum'})
print (df)
    Name  one  two
0   John  A+P   50
1   Alex    B   40
2  David    C   50
3  Harry  A+P  100
```

Comment: One doubt can `groupby` be called on multple columns to `agg` and get the `sum`

Comment: @suryarahul - yse, sure, add another column(s) like `.agg({'one':'+'.join, 'two':'sum', 'col':'sum'})`

Comment: Ok :)

I will try, Thanks again